# Can I share the scanner functionality of a multifunction printer over a network running CUPS print server?

Tags: linux, network-share, printing, cups

I have a Debian box running cups on which I share out my laser printer to all the other machines in my home network.  I am in the market for an upgrade to a color laser multifunction (print/scan/fax) printer and I want to keep the same network setup.

I do not anticipate any issues sharing the printing function via cups, but how does scanning work?  Can I scan into printer and somehow push the image to a machine?  Or would I fire off the scan process from the client machine needing the scanned image?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll need to configure [SANE](http://www.sane-project.org/) to work [over the network](http://penguin-breeder.org/sane/saned/).

Comment: exactly what i was looking for - now i'm wondering if i really need it with the new printers having network capability built in.

Answer (score 3):

That depends on the scanning device in question. CUPS won't be able to handle it. One method, that we're looking to use campus wide, is to specify a drop-zone for these MFPs to drop scans. This is a Samba share with a unique folder for each MFP. It does depend on if the MFP can drop files on a SMB share, which not all do. Many can send emails, so you might be able to use a shared mailbox of some kind.

Of course, this is for MFPs that are network-attached rather than USB attached. A lot of the newer MFPs have built-in wireless these days, which implies they may have some of these features.

Comment: i just had the thought that if i can connect directly into the network then i don't really need a cups print server - my current printer is 10+ years old and i only have lpt port connected.

Comment: @Tone Heh, yep. Exactly that. I have a USB printer I use on my home print server. For home use, these network-attached MFPs work pretty well. Corporate use is another problem, though.